# TestCafe Get Current IP Of Proxy Being Used

Tags: proxy, ip, screen-scraping, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to know if anyone has a way to get the IP address of the currently used proxy IP of a running TestCafe test.  I would rather not add the overhead of first loading up a site that gives me the proxy IP I'm using and instead would like it if there was some internal way to discern it.

Comment: Do you mean the IP address of the machine where TestCafe is running or IP which is set via the --proxy option?

Comment: Meaning, I use crawlera proxies and for each TestCafe  test I run their API gives a new proxy ip from a random ip pool of thousands of ips. I am trying to ensure I don’t reuse a previously used IP address. Due to this condition I feel forced to use .navigateTo(whatsmyipsite) and get the displayed ip from Client. Is there a cleaner way to get the current proxy ip without hitting a whatsmyip.org type of site?

Comment: I guess it's not possible since HTTP proxy protocol used by crawlera doesn't provide any information about the external IP address to a client (a browser or a TestCafe worker). An external resource is required to detect your external IP address provided by a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much work on this, I have solved this by creating an express server, installing [request-IP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) (a node.js library which gets the requesting IP), and then basically setting up an endpoint `/givemyip` to ping that first before actually navigating to the target testing page. Doing so let me view every single proxy in the terminal. I then simply wrote each IP to MongoDB along with the result data from each test.  Solved!